# Ghostscript Failed to Execute in MAMP PRO

Tags: php, imagemagick, mamp, ghostscript, mamp-pro

I'm using MAMP PRO on my local machine and I have enabled the imagick extension in the PHP config file provided by MAMP PRO.  I can see Imagick is listed under phpinfo().  I am attempting to create a thumbnail from an Illustrator file (.ai), but when I try this code...

```
$temp_file2 = '/path/to/vector.ai';
$image = new Imagick($temp_file2);
```

I get this error...

```
FailedToExecuteCommand `"/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72"  "-sOutputFile=/var/tmp/magick-2814rSVJPY2macFe%d" "-f/var/tmp/magick-2814Z5tbjlN3yNHL" "-f/var/tmp/magick-2814fken20MxIbeq"' (-1) @ error/utility.c/SystemCommand/2051
```

So it can't execute the Ghostscript executable file?  I thought MAMP PRO would just take care of this itself once I enabled Imagick?

Comment: Dumb question but, do you have Ghostscript installed as well as ImageMagick ? They are separate installations....

Comment: Well MAMP PRO 3 says that it comes with both of those.  So no I didn't install them, MAMP PRO did.

Comment: Well the first thing I'd do is check that they are both installed, and can be executed from the given directory. There's also some odd use of quotes going on there, I know nothing about PHP so it maybe correct, but some portions of that command line are quoted, other are not. I'd have expected everything to be in one quoted string, but that may be misleading.

Comment: You should also check your ImageMagick is configured to work with Ghostscript. I don't know much about IM but I believe "convert -list configure" will list the delegates, you need to see if GS is in the list under delegates. FWIW that error message appears to come from ImageMagick, though I think you may be missing part of the error string.